# Section Lines Disappearing Graphical Issue

Tags: infopath, infopath2010, infopath-2007

I am having a display issue with Infopath.  My section lines and section text disappear in the form designer.  The lines are initially there but then disappear after I click a few times and scroll.  They still exist and can be clicked but I cannot seem them.  I am not sure right now what exactly is causing them to disappear.

I am able to get them back again by switching views.  This problem occurs both with infopath 2010, and 2007.  It also happens to different forms.  So it appears to be some sort of display issue.  I have not noticed display issue's in any other programs.

I think the likely cause is because I recently formatted my computer, swapped graphics cards for the same model number but what looks like a newer revision because the fan failed on the last card.  My specs may be relevant:  I am using an AMD FirePro V4900, latest driver 13.352.1009 as of posting.  3 Monitor setup.  Windows 7 x64.

Has anyone else run into this and found a fix?

Comment: Can I get any screen shot of that form in web as well as a template?

Comment: @SAT I finally have a chance to work on this again.  [Initially](http://imgur.com/OIJuu4J), [Few clicks/Scrolls Later](http://imgur.com/6GSCm29)  If I change views it goes back to normal for a short period of time.